# What is CSS lone * selector good for?

Tags: css

There is one CSS selector I cannot figure good use for.

```
* {
    /* Some styles */
}
```

I know it is used to set styles on every element on a page. Some people use it to reset every padding and margin to 0. Other ideas?

I don't ask about hacks. I don't ask about combination like `something *` or `something * something_else`. I ask only about lone `*`.

---

This questions is similar, but little different.
[in what conditions we can use css * selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894406/in-what-conditions-we-can-use-css-selector)
I only ask about lone `*`.

---

It was my mistake to ask this question on Stack Overflow. There is probably no good answer. It could only be something like open poll about weird ideas. There was too much of my personal opinion in the first version of this entry too.

Comment: You clearly know what it is used for; you are just using this question to express your opinion that doing so is useless and challenging people to disagree with you... vote to close.

Comment: I find `* {display:none !important}` useful ;)

Comment: I'll bite. And if you're really bored @Joseph, setting the above in someone's user agent style sheet is a really mean prank.

Comment: @Blake that would be awesome XD

Comment: @Domenic You may be right. It is probably too open.

Answer (score 4):

It is important and useful if you want to SPECIFICALLY override inheritance. Applying a font and color to body for example will be overridden by child elements. The * will not unless an element is specifically overridden.

Ex:

```
* { color: #FFF }

#Wrapper
{
color: #000
}
```

A p element within #Wrapper will still be #FFF unless it is specifically set in the CSS above as.

```
#Wrapper p
{
color: #000;
}
```

A good writeup on it has been [done by Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006a.html).

Answer (score 1):

The universal selector is often used in reset.css (which standardize the default browser style sheet) to avoid browser quirks. There is a lot of content on why to reset and actual reset sheets, so I'll let you pick your fav.

Another important used I've seen is to provide child-selector '>' for IE.

So for example.

```
.article > p { padding: 5px; }
```

There is a good write up here if you're interesting in supporting IE and use the child selector.
http://www.sitepoint.com/erics-universal-child-selector/

Comment: Child selectors have been [supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t11) since IE7.  [H5BP](http://html5boilerplate.com/) has dropped the reset stylesheet in favor of [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) -- a welcome move since I've [always](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/) [hated](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20080419/reset-style-sheets-are-bad/)--and never used--the reset stylesheet.