# What does the * * CSS selector do?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Recently I came across `* *` in [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Site reference - [Site Link](http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/how-to-stop-your-wordpress-blog-getting-hacked).

For a single `*` usage in CSS style sheet, Internet and Stack Overflow is flooded with examples, but I am not sure about using two `* *` symbol in CSS.

I googled it, but unable to find any relevant information about this, as a single `*` selects all elements, but I am not sure why the site used it twice. What is the missing part for this, and why is this hack used (if it is a hack)?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Just like any other time you put two selectors one after another (for example `li a`), you get the descendant combinator. So `* *` is any element that is a descendant of any other element — in other words, any element that *isn't* the root element of the whole document.

Comment: thx for the reply..this is what I was thinking for but not sure so thought to ask from the community..will accept it soon +1

Comment: just one more thing to ask--is it really relevant to use * * ? as although I grasp the concept but not getting it in practical terms :(

Comment: @swapnesh it looks like a browser hack. There's a `* { font-size: XXX }` rule and a `* * { font-size: YYY }` rule. One of them applies to most browsers, and the other one applies to browsers with a certain bug, although I don't have patience to figure out the details. It's similar to the `* html` hack that used to be in common use to detect old IE.

Comment: thx for adding the last detailed block under comments..it is almost a perfect one..no need to do more brain storming for that :)  thx a lot :)

Comment: Note that in the manner of `* html`, `* *` *will* match the html element in IE6.

Answer (score 80):

**Just a little big example:**

Try to add this on your site:

```
* { outline: 2px dotted red; }
* * { outline: 2px dotted green; }
* * * { outline: 2px dotted orange; }
* * * * { outline: 2px dotted blue; }
* * * * * { outline: 1px solid red; }
* * * * * * { outline: 1px solid green; }
* * * * * * * { outline: 1px solid orange; }
* * * * * * * * { outline: 1px solid blue; }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/sFSad/

---

**Example 2:**

[image: What does the * * CSS selector do?]

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/sFSad/34/

Comment: This isn't strictly the answer, but what a lovely visualisation!

Comment: @l2aelba really a nice piece of explanation :) +1

Answer (score 33):

`* *` Matches everything except the top-level element, e.g., `html`.

Comment: Thanks Joe, tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nNCVY/) and also according to comments above: the `* *` selector is equivalent to `html *` for all browsers except the old good IE6 :-)

Comment: @Stano `* *` is equivalent of `html *` ... for a HTML file. But CSS may be used to style other kind of documents (SVG notably).

Answer (score 11):

`*` means apply given styles to all the elements.

`* *` means apply given styles to all the element's child elements.
Example:

```
body > * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This applies margin styles to all the child elements of body. Same way,

```
* * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

applies `margin: 0` to `*`'s child elements. In short, it applies `margin: 0` to almost every element.

Generally, one `*` is enough. There's no need for two `* *`.

Comment: thx for the explanation +1 ..although even I am not sure for what you just mentioned in the last line "Generally, * is enough. There's no need for * *. I guess."

Comment: `* *` applies styles to *descendant* elements, not child elements. Child elements would be `>` as in your example, not the space. Descendant and child are not the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

That selects all elements nested inside another element in much the same way `div a` would select all `<a>` elements nested somewhere inside a `<div>` element.