# Is the all selector Hack or standard?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is this a hack or w3c standard?

Style:

```
* { background: #73102a; padding:20px;}
* * { background: #a6386b; }
* * * { background: #3b574b; }
* * * * { background: #15bf5f; }
* * * * * { background: #62bf54; }
```

Markup:

```
<header>
    <menu>
        <li>
            <a>
                <span>Menu</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </menu>
</header>
```

[Result:](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/FV4qd/)

[image]

Comment: Why should it be a hack? The last selector that applies to an element wins. The first one applies to all elements, but the last one only to elements five levels deep. If you change the order, the result will be different.

Comment: it's of course standard, a normal children selector.

Comment: @FelixKling yes but since it is called `Universal Selector` i was wundering because you can not write `[id=][id=][id=]` for ids or `[class=][class=][class=]` for class

Comment: Because `#` by itself is not a selector. `#` and `.` have to followed by other characters. So, `#abc` or `.xyz` are valid selectors. And of course you can write `.xyz .xyz .xyz`. `*` on the other hand is a "complete" selector on its own. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Comment: @FelixKling: "The last selector that applies to an element wins. The first one applies to all elements, but the last one only to elements five levels deep. If you change the order, the result will be different."  No, it doesn't work that way.  Specificity is the tie breaker.  The outcome should not change if the rule order is changed.

Comment: @recursive: Right, my comment wasn't very accurate. The order matters if the specificity is the same, which is the case here. The universal selector doesn't contribute to specificity, so all of these rules have the same specificity.

Comment: @FelixKling: My bad.  I thought universal selectors contributed to specificity somewhere.

Comment: @recursive: No worries, I thought so too, but according to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity, they don't. And thinking about it, it kind of makes sense, since you probably want *every* selector to be more specific than universal selector.

Comment: See also: [What does the * * CSS selector do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607873/what-does-the-css-selector-do)

Comment: @BoltClock thank you for the link "any element that isn't the root element of the whole document.", that is the same as `*:not(:root)` i think or is the any difference?

Comment: @kougiland: Specifically for `* *`, yes it's the same as `:not(:root)`. There is no equivalent for `* * *` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a hack.

`*` - means anything

`* *` - means anything that is a child (or grand*N-child) of any element

`* * *` - means anything that is a child (or grand*N-child) of anything that is a child (or grand*N-child) of anything.

And so on.

Not a good practice to use such selectors, I guess. But perfectly normal ones if to speak about standards.

Also, please note that `*` will include `html` element itself, but `* *` will not. `* * *` will not include `body` as well. And so on. So, the number of elements that they select is different. But the real problem is that they select huge amount of elements (if your page is not that simple as in the example) causing inefficient behavior of your page in browsers.

Answer (score 2):

`*` selects all elements.

`* *` selections all elements that are a child of any element.

`* * *` selections all elements that are a child of any element that is a child of any element.

`* * * *` selections all elements that are a child of any element that is a child of any element that is a child of any element.

… I think you can see where this is going. It's just a combination of the [`*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) (any element) selector and th  (descendant) selector (not a browser-related hack).

I'd recommend against it since you shouldn't select "any element", "any element n levels down", or "any element n or more levels down" (uses of `*`). It's a broad selector which is better replaced with something like `header > menu > li > a > span`.

Comment: -1. I don't see here where is the answer to the above question... consider changing you answer content, and I'll consider remove the down vote. 1st you perform obvious observations against something not asked. then you do recommendations about not using it, but IS this an HACK? YES or NO?

Comment: I'd recommend against ...but what about reseting padding and margin *{padding:0;margin:0;}

Comment: @kougiland Unless you need to support really old browsers, you don't need a reset anyway. But if you do, you can break all the rules.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` aka any element selector is a Standard CSS selector as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) on the section **Information: Selectors based on relationships**.

In what concerns to whether or not it is good practice to use it, its arguable, and the right answer to that question is, it depends:

- If you know that a portion of HTML is static, and you are aiming to precisely target a specific element and you can't are a style to do it other way, then use the any element to grab siblings;
- If you can follow other approaches, more generic, like defining a class or id, then don't use the any element selector, as is main envolve further maintenance when dealing with scenarios that may envolve a more dynamic change of HTML.

**Note (Performance)**

**(...)** In the usual way, if you make a selector more specific, then you increase its priority.

If you use these techniques, you avoid the need to specify class or id attributes on so many tags in your document. Instead, CSS does the work.

**In large designs where speed is important, you can make your stylesheets more efficient by avoiding complex rules that depend on relationships between elements.** **(...)**